# Having an array that points to multiple LUT with different sizes in C

Tags: c, pointers, segmentation-fault, lookup-tables

I'm doing a program that sorts a stack of number using two stacks for a school project, and I want to handle the cases where the size of the stack is inferior or egal to 5 by a brute force method, for that I have different structs that contains lookup tables with an array of int arrays representing the order of the numbers (for every possible order), and an array of function pointer arrays containing the corresponding operation sequence to sort them, and each of these structs correspond to a specific array size (2, 3, 4, 5). And to avoid a hugly `if` forest, I'd like to access them using a while loop with a common struct (`t_combi`) that has pointers to the different datas, but apparently it doesn't work, I somehow lose the address of my global arrays because I get a segfault (trying to access non allocated data with valgrind) at the first iteration when I compare the orders.

Code:

```c
//  brute_force.h

#ifndef BRUTE_FORCE_H
# define BRUTE_FORCE_H

# include "resolver.h"

# define CNT_2 2
# define CNT_3 6
# define CNT_4 24
# define CNT_5 120

typedef struct s_mlx    *t_mlxptr;
typedef const char      *(*t_op)(t_stack *, t_stack *);

typedef struct  s_combi {
    int     cnt;
    int     **order;
    t_op    **op;
}   t_combi;

static const struct {
    int     cnt;
    int     order[CNT_2][2];
    t_op    op[CNT_2][2];
}   g_2combi = {
        .cnt = CNT_2,
        .order = {
            {0, 1},
            {1, 0}
        },
        .op = {
            {NULL},
            {sa, NULL}
        }
};

static const struct {
    int     cnt;
    int     order[CNT_3][3];
    t_op    op[CNT_3][3];
}   g_3combi = {
        .cnt = CNT_3,
        .order = {
            {0, 1, 2},
            {0, 2, 1},
            {1, 0, 2},
            ...
        },
        .op = {
            {NULL},
            {rra, sa, NULL},
            {sa, NULL},
            ...
        }
};

static const struct {
    int     cnt;
    int     order[CNT_4][4];
    t_op    op[CNT_4][7];
}   g_4combi = {
    .cnt = CNT_4,
    .order = {
        {0, 1, 2, 3},
        {0, 1, 3, 2},
        {0, 2, 1, 3},
        ...
    },
    .op = {
        {NULL},
        {pb, rra, sa, pa, NULL},
        {ra, sa, rra, NULL},
        ...
    }
};

static const struct {
    int     cnt;
    int     order[120][5];
    t_op    op[120][10];
}   g_5combi = {
    .cnt = CNT_5,
    .order = {
        {0, 1, 2, 3, 4},
        {0, 1, 2, 4, 3},
        {0, 1, 3, 2, 4},
        ...
    },
    .op = {
        {NULL},
        {rra, rra, sa, ra, ra, NULL},
        {pb, pb, sa, pa, pa, NULL},
        {pb, pb, rra, pa, pa, NULL},
        ...
    }
};

int brute_force(t_mlxptr mlx, t_stack *st[2], t_queue *instr);

#endif

// brute_force.c

#include <brute_force.h>
#include <resolver.h>

bool    same_order(const int *a, const int *b, size_t size)
{
    size_t  i = 0;

    while (++i < size)
    {
        if ((a[i - 1] < a[i] && b[i - 1] > b[i])
        || (a[i - 1] > a[i] && b[i - 1] < b[i]))
            return (false);
    }
    return (true);
}

void    apply_instructions(t_mlxptr mlx, t_stack *st[2], t_op *op, t_queue *instr)
{
    while (*op)
    {
        add_op(mlx, *op, st, instr); // function from resolver.h
        ++op;
    }
}

void    init_combi(t_combi combi[4])
{
    combi[0] = (t_combi) {
        .cnt = g_2combi.cnt,
        .order = (int**)g_2combi.order,
        .op = (t_op **)g_2combi.op
    };
    combi[1] = (t_combi) {
        .cnt = g_3combi.cnt,
        .order = (int**)g_3combi.order,
        .op = (t_op **)g_3combi.op
    };
    combi[2] = (t_combi) {
        .cnt = g_4combi.cnt,
        .order = (int**)g_4combi.order,
        .op = (t_op **)g_4combi.op
    };
    combi[3] = (t_combi) {
        .cnt = g_5combi.cnt,
        .order = (int**)g_5combi.order,
        .op = (t_op **)g_5combi.op
    };
}


int brute_force(t_mlxptr mlx, t_stack *st[2], t_queue *instr)
{
    const int *const    a_raw = stkcbegin(st[ST_A]); // pointer to a int array
    const size_t        size = stksize(st[ST_A]); // nbcount
    int                 i;

    t_combi             combi[4];
    
    init_combi(combi);
    if (stksorted(st[ST_A]))
        return (0);
    if (size > 5)
        return (1);
    i = -1;
    while (++i < combi[size - 2].cnt)
    {
        if (same_order(combi[size - 2].order[i], a_raw, size))
            apply_instructions(mlx, st, combi[size - 2].op[i], instr);
    }
    return (0);
}
```

Comment: Pointers and arrays are different things with different layouts. The type casts in `init_combi` are masking the error.

Comment: For example, `g_combi2.order` has type `int [CNT_2][2]` which decays to `int (*)[2]`, but you are casting it to `int **`. `int **` is a "pointer to pointer to `int`", but the array object `g_combi2.order` contains no pointers.

Comment: Also, as a matter of style, it is a bad idea to declare static variables in a header file, unless you really want each .c file including the header to have its own local copy of the variables.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The main problem is that you are casting a pointer to an array of some type to a pointer to a pointer of some type. For example, in this code:

```
void    init_combi(t_combi combi[4])
{
    combi[0] = (t_combi) {
        .cnt = g_2combi.cnt,
        .order = (int**)g_2combi.order,
        .op = (t_op **)g_2combi.op
    };
    /* ... */
}
```

`g_2combi.order` is 2-dimensional array of `int`: `int [CNT_2][2]`. In the initializer, the value is converted to a pointer to its first element. The type of the element is `int [2]` (array length 2 of `int`), so the type of the pointer to an element is `int (*)[2]` (pointer to array length 2 of `int`). However, the type cast operation is converting it to a pointer to an incompatible type `int **` (pointer to pointer to `int`). `combi[0].order[0]` should be of type `int *`, which is not compatible with the underlying object's type: `int [2]`.

Similarly, `g_2combi.op` is a 2-dimensional array of `t_op`: `t_op [CNT_2][2]`. In the initializer, the value is converted to a pointer to its first element of type `t_op [2]` (array length 2 of `t_op`), so the pointer is of type `t_op (*)[2]` (pointer to array length 2 of `t_op`). The type cast operation is converting the pointer to `t_op **` (pointer to pointer to `t_op`). `combi[0].op[0]` should be of type `t_op *`, which is not compatible with the underlying object's type: `t_op [2]`.

One way to solve the problem is to define all the variables `g_2combi`, `g_3combi`, etc. to be of the same type `t_combi`. Keeping everything constant, [compound literals](https://en.cppreference.com/w/c/language/compound_literal) could be used to initialize the pointers in `g_2combi.order` etc.  For example:

```
typedef struct  s_combi {
    int     cnt;
    const int * const *order;
    const t_op * const *op;
} t_combi;

static const t_combi g_2combi = {
    .cnt = CNT_2,
    .order = (const int * const []){
        (const int []){0, 1},
        (const int []){1, 0}
    },
    .op = (const t_op * const []){
        (const t_op []){NULL},
        (const t_op []){sa, NULL}
    }
};

/* define g_3combi etc. in a similar way to the above. */

void    init_combi(t_combi combi[4])
{
    combi[0] = g_2combi;
    combi[1] = g_3combi;
    combi[2] = g_4combi;
    combi[3] = g_5combi;
}
```

(Due to the added `const`ness above, the `op` parameter of the `apply_instruction` function would need to be changed from `t_op *op` to `const t_op *op`.)

Comment: Thanks ! I kind of wanted to do something like that but i didn't know how to do it

Comment: @Fayeure Compound literals are very useful for this sort of thing. The same sort of thing can be done without them, but the pointers to compound literal arrays would need to be replaced with pointers to named arrays initialized outside the current object. Compound literals are basically anonymous, initialized objects.

Answer (score 0):

One big problem is that you are hiding pointers behind typedef. This serves one single purpose: to confuse the programmer and everyone else reading the code.

For example  `t_op **op;` expanded without typedef creates a function pointer of type

```
typedef const char      *(***t_op)(t_stack *, t_stack *);
```

As you hopefully can tell, that's simply madness. You need to get rid of these typedefs and needless layers of multiple indirection, before you can do anything else.

A sensible `typedef` of a function pointer might look like this (it's actually a typedef of a function):

```
typedef char* t_op (t_stack*, t_stack*);
```

Which you then use as `t_op* op`.

Overall, your program is *way* too complicated for something that sounds like a fairly trivial task. There shouldn't be any casts anywhere, as another example - all these do is to hide away bugs.

Comment: Overall, check out the "KISS principle". And also keep this quote by C guru Brian Kernighan in mind: _"Everyone knows that debugging is twice as hard as writing a program in the first place. So if you're as clever as you can be when you write it, how will you ever debug it?"_

Comment: Okay, that's a problem, but that's not the main problem, if I can't cast it to pointers, how could I have a pointer to arrays of different sizes

Comment: @Fayeure There are several ways. Wrap them in structs, use malloc, or use pointer to VLA etc. But the code is frankly not salvageable, you should start over from the requirements: what should this code do? And then investigate the best way to implement that. Because a lot of this extra complexity here originates from you spotting some problem but using much too complex features to solve it.